# Most efficient way to connect to MySQL in multiple PHP files

Tags: php, mysql

I have pages that have content dynamically added through mySQL queries. Most of these pages make use of php file includes, so my header, navigation, body, and footer are in separate files. My MySQL connection code is also in a separate file. Currently I am connecting to my database, querying content, echoing the conent, and closing the database in EACH file.

My question is this: Is there any reason for or against having my connection script included and database opened and closed in each file (header, navigation, body, and footer) since they are all part of the same page? Or should ALL of my PHP code connecting to the database be in the same file?

I am self taught, and this sort of theory has never really been explained in any of the sources I have learned from.

Comment: You would benefit a lot from looking into Object Oriented programming. Learning to work with classes/objects would really boost your understanding and ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or should ALL of my PHP code connecting to the database be in the same
>   file?

This is what you should aim for. Opening and closing db connections in each file violates the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Answer (score 1):

Two particular [best practices](http://docforge.com/wiki/Best_practices) apply:

- Abstract out your database connectivity to one common class or set of functions.  This will let you change your implementation details later and also help you track down issues.  For example, if you want to start logging all queries at the application level you can add that to your one database class.  More importantly this will let you trap database errors consistently.
- Don't copy code in multiple places.  Manage identical logic in only one place.  For example, your database connection logic should only be implemented once.